# Racket db disconnect raises an exception

Tags: sqlite, racket

I'm using an sqlite database with racket's db module. After handling a failed insert or update due to duplicate key violations, if I try to disconnect using

```
(disconnect dbconn)
```

it successfully disconnects, but I get the following error

```
disconnect: abort due to contraint violation
```

I'm currently wrapping the disconnect function with

```
(define (my-disconnect dbconn)
     (with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (e) (void))])
         (disconnect dbconn)))
```

but is there a way to stop disconnect from raising the error?

**Update:**
This seems to be a bug in Racket 5.2 that got fixed in later versions. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Racket 5.2. Here's a small program with this problem.

```
#lang racket

(require db)

(define db-file "db.sqlite")
(define dbconn (sqlite3-connect #:database db-file #:mode 'create))

(query-exec dbconn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cats (\"cat_pk\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, \"cat_name\" TEXT)")

(query-exec dbconn "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kittens (\"kitten_pk\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, \"kitten_name\" TEXT, cat_fk INTEGER NOT NU    LL, UNIQUE (cat_fk, kitten_name), FOREIGN KEY(cat_fk) REFERENCES cats (cat_pk))")

(query-exec dbconn "INSERT INTO cats (cat_name) VALUES (\"Dorothy\")")

(query-exec dbconn "INSERT INTO kittens (kitten_name, cat_fk) VALUES (\"John\", 1)")

(with-handlers [(exn:fail? (lambda (e) "Opps"))]
     (query-exec dbconn "INSERT INTO kittens (kitten_name, cat_fk) VALUES (\"John\", 1)"))

(disconnect dbconn)
```

In Racket 5.2 I get

```
"Opps"
disconnect: abort due to contraint violation

 === context ===
/usr/share/racket/collects/db/private/sqlite3/connection.rkt:257:8
/usr/share/racket/collects/db/private/sqlite3/connection.rkt:168:14: for-loop
/usr/share/racket/collects/db/private/sqlite3/connection.rkt:161:6: go
/users/user/www/test/test.rkt: [running body]
```

where as in Racket 6.2 I only get

```
"Opps"
```

Comment: From looking at the source code, it looks like `disconnect` should call the C function `sqlite3_close`, and throw an exception unless it returns `SQLITE_DONE`. The weird thing is that the error you're getting corresponds to `SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`, but the only other thing that `sqlite3_close` can return besides `SQLITE_DONE` is `SQLITE_BUSY` ("The database file is locked.").

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this error. I recommend filing a Racket bug report (using either DrRacket or bugs.racket-lang.org). If you can provide a tiny program that triggers the error, that would be very helpful too.